# induction of magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

I am interested to know about if a charge particle is at rest and the body is rotating with constant angular velocity but does not changing its position,only its symmetry changes,but the body is axially symeetric, then magnetic field will induced or not?
Because we know that $v=r\times w$ 
if body is moving with constant angular velocity then there is relative velocity..
can any one explain 
I shall be very thankfull.

Comment: Your question is not clear - what is the body you refer to?

Comment: any neutral body roatating
w.r.t that body magnetic field will induce or not if only rotating

Comment: And where is the charge located?

Comment: @Abhijeet Melkani the charge particle is at rest any where you can consider but the body that is axially symmetric is rotating

Answer (score 0):

The body is not an inertial frame of reference (as it rotates and hence its velocity is changing) and so it is not correct to apply Maxwell's laws from such a frame.

Now, if a reference frame was uniformly moving relative to the charge, then yes it would experience a magnetic field.

Comment: May be you are not considering my question
the body is rotating with axial symmetry and also it is neutral 
and the charge is at rest 
now I am asking whether magnetic field induced or not?